# In c# compact-framework, how do you do a SQLite transaction while keeping foreign key constraints in an open connection?

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, compact-framework

I am creating an application in Windows Forms .Net Compact Framework 3.5 with a backing SQLite database. I am needing to keep an open connection to the database for performance reasons, and I am needing to use transactions to execute multiple updates for the possibility of rollback.

There are foreign key constraints in some of the SQLite tables, and by default foreign key enforcement is off, so I had to manually turn them on when opening the connection from the application to the database.

The problem now is that transactions do not allow foreign key constraints:
(https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys)

So when I run the the update statements, they fail and the transaction rolls back.

I tried manually turning the foreign key constraint off before the transaction, and then the updates succeeded. But when I tried turning the foreign key constraint back on after the transaction, the updates failed.

I need the foreign key constraints to be on, but they fail during transactions, and I cant simply turn them off, run a transaction, and then turn them back on. So what should I do?

```
using (var cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand(Con))
{
    cmd1.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0"; //turn foreign key contraint off before transaction
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                      
}

var cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand(Con);
using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = Con.BeginTransaction())
{
    //run update commands here

    transaction.Commit();                       //run transaction
}

using (var cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand(Con))
{
    cmd3.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1"; //turn foreign key constraint back on after transaction
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();                      //this doesnt work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have foreign keys enabled during transactions. You just can't turn them on or off during transactions - you have to turn them on before starting the transaction.

It's probably easiest to turn on the pragma when you open the connection - and then you can forget about it.

This works fine for me:

```
// Con is a SQLite connection, that has been opened.    
using (var cmd = Con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

using (var cmd = Con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"
    CREATE TABLE A(id integer not null primary key);
    CREATE TABLE B(id integer not null primary key, a_id integer, FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCES A(id))
    ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

try
{
    using (var transaction = Con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var cmd = Con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO A VALUES(1); INSERT INTO A VALUES(2); INSERT INTO B VALUES(1, NULL); INSERT INTO B VALUES(2, 1);";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var cmd = Con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO B VALUES(3, 55);";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //Will crash beceause of invalid reference
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
} catch(DbException) {
    // Ignore transaction failure in this example   
    if(!e.Message.Contains("foreign key constraint failed"))
        throw;
}

using (var cmd = Con.CreateCommand())
{
    // Validate that nothing was inserted in the failed transaction
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A";
    Debug.Assert((long)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0);
}
```

Comment: I do enable foreign keys at the opening of the connection. The problem is that without turning them back off before running the updates, my tables do not update. Nothing is thrown, but the table isn't updated so its like something failed and the transaction rolled back. When I do turn them off, then the tables update. I do not think its a foreign key failing, because there is only two keys and I manually made sure that nothing is violated. Also to note, the exact same sql code works in SQLite Expert (sqlite3.dll 3.31.1) but not in the program (sqlite.interop.112).

Comment: I can update the database inside the transaction as well - if the transaction succeeds, the database is updated as expected, and the data is there for the next statement (inside transaction or not)

Comment: I figured out the issue.The transaction was working fine. The problem was shortly after the code I showed, I was using a sql REPLACE statement to the parent table of the foreign key, which deleted the record and then reinserted, which cascade deleted the record that I was updating in the transaction. So thank you for your help in showing that transactions do work with foreign key constraints on, because it caused me to look deeper in my own code instead of assuming something was wrong with SQLite.